Python-Polars: Select rows and use as headers with separator
Description
Since Polars doesn't work with multi-index headers like Pandas does, I'd like to know if there's a native way to do the following:
My current implementation has to go through Pandas first and then convert it to a pl.DataFrame.

# ----- Multiindex DataFrame -----

arrays = [["A", "A", "B", "B"], ["one", "two", "one", "two"]]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
pandas_multiindex_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], columns=index)
print(pandas_multiindex_df)

    A       B    
  one two one two
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8

Note: This simulates an input excel that is separated by headers, so I will always have the data like this

They way y work is:

Flat the pandas_df

def multiindex_to_flatted_header(df: pd.DataFrame, sep: str = "-") -> pd.DataFrame:
    flat_columns = [f"{col[0]}{sep}{col[1]}" for col in df.columns]

    df_flat = df.copy()
    df_flat.columns = flat_columns

    return df_flat

pandas_flatted_df = multiindex_to_flatted_header(pandas_multiindex_df)
print(pandas_flatted_df)

   A-one  A-two  B-one  B-two
0      1      2      3      4
1      5      6      7      8


move to polars


polars_flatted_df = pl.from_pandas(pandas_flatted_df)
print(polars_flatted_df)

shape: (2, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ A-one ┆ A-two ┆ B-one ┆ B-two │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 1     ┆ 2     ┆ 3     ┆ 4     │
│ 5     ┆ 6     ┆ 7     ┆ 8     │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘

# Do stuff with polars performing operations


Back to pandas


pandas_flatted_df_2 =polars_flatted_df.to_pandas()

def flatted_to_multiindex_header(df: pd.DataFrame, sep: str = "-") -> pd.DataFrame:
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [col.split(sep, 1) if sep in col else [col, ""] for col in df.columns]
    )
    return df


pandas_multiindex_df_2 = flatted_to_multiindex_header(pandas_flatted_df_2)
print(pandas_multiindex_df_2)

    A       B    
  one two one two
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8

Note: I'm going back to pandas only because I need the resulting excel to have a presentation, but this step is not necessary

The question is:
there any way to do the same (Flatten an excel_file/pandas_multiindex) with polars? like, use_rows_and_join_with_any_separator_and_use_as_header.
I think doing this on my way could cause performance issues when use large datasets, with a polars implementation, will be boost.

Buenas, esto es StackOverflow EN ESPAÑOL, traduce o dirigete a [SO]

Hola! No me di cuenta, gracias!
